# SQL Server In-Memory OLTP not supported

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to test SQL Server 2014 In-Memory OLTP tables but I'm getting an error message when trying to create the filegroup.

```
ALTER DATABASE Test_DB ADD FILEGROUP Test_FG CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA
```

> FILEGROUP ... CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA' failed because it is not
>   supported in the edition of this SQL Server instance

My database version is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64)

All the docs I'm reading are telling me this should be supported in SQL Server 2014, anybody have an ideas on what I've missed please?

Comment: which SQL Server edition?

Comment: It is only supported in Enterprise edition of SQL Server 2014. Which edition do you have?

Comment: It is also available in the Developer Edition, which is generally the same as the Enterprise edition

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm using Standard edition.

I'll upgrade and test using dev edition.

Frustrating because the article I'm following on msdn doesn't refer to the edition, just the version!

Answer (score 0):

Hey there are certain limitations in In-Memory OLTP of SQL server 2014.
This link lists them all, have a look.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246937(v=sql.120).aspx

And the IN-Memory feature is not supported on Express edition of sql server 2014. Try Developer/SP1(service pack 1 - evaluation edition).

You can find the pre-reqs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn170449.aspx